# Pandas JSON Nesting

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested, pandas-groupby

At present I have a scraped url table in a Pandas dataframe. The aim is to spit out a nested json output and with the use of the groupby() and Lambda functions I have nearly what I am looking for. I have been learning this as I go along so might not be great code.

```
{
"Field (Discovery)": "33/9-6 DELTA",
"NPDID information carrier": 44576,
"MonthlyProduction": [
  {
    "yyyymm": "2009.07.0",
    "Oil - saleable [mill Sm3]": 0.00025,
    "Gas - saleable [bill Sm3]": 0,
    "NGL - saleable [mill Sm3]": -0.00004,
    "Condensate - saleable [mill Sm3]": 0,
    "Oil equivalents - saleable [mill Sm3]": 0.00021,
    "Water - wellbores [mill Sm3]": 0.00051
  }
```

What I am looking for is how to break the nested part of the JSON down a further level so taking what is a column and the value beneath "yyyymm" and nest that as follows:

```
{
"Field (Discovery)": "33/9-6 DELTA",
"NPDID information carrier": 44576,
"MonthlyProduction": [
  {
    "yyyymm": "2009.07.0",
    "Oil – saleable: [
        {
         "Value":0.00025,
         "Unit":  mill Sm3,
        }
       ]
    "Gas - saleable":[
        {
        "Value": 0,
        "Unit":  bill Sm3,
        }
       ]
        "NGL - saleable ": -0.00004, etc
        "Condensate - saleable [mill Sm3]": 0, etc
```

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
from datetime import datetime as dt
import datetime
import pandas as pd

starttime = dt.now()

#Agent detail to prevent scraping bot detection
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
header = {'User-Agent' : user_agent }


# Webpage connection
html ="http://factpages.npd.no/ReportServer?/FactPages/TableView/
field_production_monthly&rs:Command=Render&rc:Toolbar=false&
rc:Parameters=f&Top100=False&IpAddress=108.171.128.174&CultureCode=en"

r=requests.get(html, headers=header)
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'a133'})

#Pandas dataframe 
df = pd.read_html(str(table), header=0)[0]
df['yyyymm'] = df['Year'].map(str)+df['Month'].map(str)
#df['NPDID information carrier'].astype(int)

df.info()

result = (df.groupby(["Field (Discovery)","NPDID information carrier"], 
as_index=False)
         .apply(lambda x: x[[ 'yyyymm','Oil - saleable [mill Sm3]','Gas - 
         saleable [bill Sm3]','NGL - saleable [mill Sm3]','Condensate - 
         saleable [mill Sm3]','Oil equivalents - saleable [mill Sm3]','Water 
         - wellbores [mill Sm3]' ]].to_dict('r'))
         .reset_index()
         .rename(columns={0: 'MonthlyProduction'})
         .to_json(orient='records'))

#print(result)
#print(json.dumps(json.loads(result), indent=2, sort_keys=True))

#Time
runtime = dt.now() - starttime
print(runtime)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
#define columns names
c1 = ["Field (Discovery)","NPDID information carrier"]
c2 = ['Oil - saleable [mill Sm3]', 
      'Gas - saleable [bill Sm3]', 
      'NGL - saleable [mill Sm3]',
      'Condensate - saleable [mill Sm3]', 
      'Oil equivalents - saleable [mill Sm3]', 
      'Water - wellbores [mill Sm3]']

#change values to dictionaries
def f(x):
    a = x.name.split('[')[1].strip(']')
    return list(zip([{'Unit': a}]*len(x),x))

df[c2] = df[c2].applymap(lambda x: {'Value': x}).apply(f)

#rename columns for remove `[]`
d = dict(zip(df[c2].columns, df[c2].columns.str.split('\s+\[').str[0]))
df = df.rename(columns=d)

#a bit improve your solution
j = (df.groupby(c1)
       .apply(lambda x: x[['yyyymm'] + list(d.values())].to_dict('r'))
       .reset_index(name='MonthlyProduction')
       .to_json(orient='records'))
```

EDIT:

```
def f(x):
    a = x.name.split('[')[1].strip(']')
    return [({'Unit': a, 'Value': i})  for i in x]

df[c2] = df[c2].apply(f)

#rename columns for remove `[]`
d = dict(zip(df[c2].columns, df[c2].columns.str.split('\s+\[').str[0]))
df = df.rename(columns=d)
#print (df.head())


#a bit improve your solution
j = (df.groupby(c1)
       .apply(lambda x: x[['yyyymm'] + list(d.values())].to_dict('r'))
       .reset_index(name='MonthlyProduction')
       .to_json(orient='records'))
```

Comment: Super, glad can help!

Comment: Have been working with this for a bit now understanding how it works etc. Is there a easy way to change the return list 'unit' and the lambda appended 'Value' so rather than `"MonthlyProduction": [{"yyyymm": "2009.03.0", "Oil - saleable": [ {  "Unit": "mill Sm3" }, {"Value": 80 } ]` it could be `"MonthlyProduction": [{"yyyymm": "2009.03.0", "Oil - saleable": [{"unit":"mill Sm3","value":"80"}` ?

Comment: Yes, sure, only change `list(zip([{'Unit': a}]*len(x),x))` to `list(zip([{'unit': a}]*len(x),x))` and `df[c2].applymap(lambda x: {'Value': x}).apply(f)` to `df[c2].applymap(lambda x: {'value': x}).apply(f)`

Comment: Sorry wasn't very clear meant more the dictionary   `[ { "Unit": "mill Sm3" }, {"Value": 80 } ]` to  `[{"Unit":"mill Sm3","Value":"80"}` kinda so the 'value' in the same dictionary as the 'unit'? My description probs aint technically correct. Guess it happens around the `applymap(lambda x: {'Value': x}).apply(f)` area

Comment: I think now it working nice, please check edited answer.

Comment: thank you so much, I spent sometime looking at  what everything does so definitely learnt a lot. Appreciate your help.